# Jquery Syntax (.a .b .c)

Tags: jquery

I have seen at many places this jquery syntax,but not able to understand what it does?

```
$('.class .class1 .class2')
```

What is the meaning of above syntax?

Comment: **it means your code is wrong** :).. it should be `$('.class .class1 .class2)` (note the extra dots ive added before class1 and class2)

Comment: Could you list an example?

Comment: read up on [selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/ http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

Answer (score 4):

This is a jQuery selector that selects a `<class2>` element within a `<class1>` element within an element with a class of `class`

Example:

```
<div class='class'>
    <class1>
        <class2></class2>
    </class1>
</div>
```

**UNLESS**

you meant to put a period at the beginning of each, in which case it means:
an element with a class of `class2` within an element with a class of `class1` within an element with a class of `class`

Example:

```
<div class='class'>
    <div class='class1'>
        <div class='class2'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This selects elements that have the `class2` class, of which are descendants of elements that have the `.class1` class, of which are descendents of elements that have the `class` class.

```
$('.class .class1 .class2')
```

The markup would look something like:

```
<div class="class">
  <div class="class1">
    <div class="class2">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If class1, class2, class were elements, you could select these so may be. But elements have classes. You must select class so:

```
$(".yourclass")
```

For selecting many divs:

```
$(".yourfirstclass,.yoursecondclass")
```

You should look up selectors in jQuery API.